# Can we remove Integration environment from magento cloud project?

Tags: deployment, integration, magento-cloud

We are having lots of extra code on integration environment. I cannot reset the commits on this branch as there are lots of issues on integration branch. So I wanted to remove integration environment and create new environment which will be the copy of staging.
So how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**:- Take a clone of Integration Environment, In case you need to recover back.

**Step 2**:- List all Environment on your Project & **Get the Environment ID**

```
magento-cloud environment:list
```

[image]

**Step 3**:- Delete using Environment ID

```
magento-cloud environment:delete <environment-ID>
```

It will ask for :-

*The environment  is currently active: deleting it will delete all associated data. Are you sure you want to delete the environment ? [Y/n] - **Press Y***

and *Delete the remote Git branch too? [Y/n] - **Press Y***

Once done your need to prune/remove branch from local also in git, using

```
git fetch --prune
```

Answer (score 0):

@sneha there are two options available where we can do this:

1. From the Magento cloud login panel, where you can create/clone the existing branch via clicking the branch icon next to git right end side in the top. It will ask for new branch name. For deactivating the integration branch for that I think you need to create a support ticket and Magento's support team will help you.
   May this will help you
   https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-webint-branch.html
2. You can create/clone staging via the command line. Please check the reference URL
   https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/env/environments-start.html
   https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html

Hope this will help you.